# Why do my query won't get all my data ? C# Access

Tags: c#, ms-access

After an hour of debugging I am trying to find why my Query returns only 1 ID where there are at least 3:

```
    public static string[] selectAGIdOfKC(string id)
    {

        int nbAg = 0;
        DataTable results = new DataTable();
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=bdd.mdb;
                                                                        Persist Security Info=False;"))
        {
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Id FROM ActionG WHERE Num_Kc = @Id", conn);
            conn.Open();

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            conn.Close();
            adapter.Fill(results);
            nbAg=results.Rows[0].ItemArray.Count();

        }

            string[] myTab = new string[nbAg];
            for (int i = 0; i < nbAg; i++)
            {
                myTab[i] = results.Rows[0].ItemArray[i].ToString();
            }
            return myTab;
    }
```

I tried to use some workarounds but nothing solves the problem of the missing returned IDs...

Can anyone help me ? Thanks for your time!

Comment: You need to debug your code. You're only keeping the count of columns rather than rows

Comment: Could you please provide some data?

Comment: Grammar fixes, removal of redundant statements.

Comment: You are only looking at the first row, regardless of how many rows were returned. `Rows[0]` is by definition the first row. Try the fix I supplied in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on how you want the results, but assuming that you want `nbAg` to contain the number of rows returned, and assuming that you want `myTab` to contain the id-values returned, your code is not written to do what you want.

Please note the ellipsis `...` - I have only modified the code that was causing your current symptoms.

```
public static string[] selectAGIdOfKC(string id)
{
    int nbAg = 0;
    ...

    nbAg = results.Rows.Count();
    string[] myTab = new string[nbAg];
    for (int i = 0; i < nbAg; i++)
    {
        myTab[i] = results.Rows[i][0].ToString(); 
                   // This is the first column of row i
    }
    return myTab;
}
```